# Upgrade ChainCode Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

This is command that am using

```
docker exec cli\
    peer chaincode upgrade \
        -o orderer.pk.snowshadow.me:7050 \
        -C mychannel -n mycc -c '{"Args": []}'\
        -p  "basic-network/chaincode" \
        -v 1.3 \
       >&upgrade.log
```

this is what am getting in upgrade.log

```
2018-11-19 13:47:41.501 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 001[0m Using default escc
2018-11-19 13:47:41.501 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 002[0m Using default vscc
Error: could not assemble transaction, err Proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg cannot get package for chaincode (mycc:1.3)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you install the new version of your chaincode before upgrade?
If you did't, try this before the upgrade command:

```
peer chaincode install -n mycc -v 1.3 -p basic-network/chaincode
```

If you did so, the error may be for some of this reasons:

1- The path parameter must be passed on the instalation I never used it in an upgrade operation, and I also don't use quotation marks on them.

2- Try passing the args like this: '{"Args":[""]}'